# Ошибка в админке wordpress «failed to open stream: No such file or directory» — как исправить?

Tags: php, wordpress, плагин

Есть сайт на `wordpress` с установленным плагином [WP Hide Post](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-hide-post/). Есть необходимость переноса сайта на новый хостинг, но решил перестраховаться и проверить его работоспособность после импорта на локальный **Open Server**. 
И не зря - вверху админпанели получаю следующие ошибки:

> fopen(C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\site/wp-content/plugins/C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\site\wp-content\plugins\wp-hide-post\wp-hide-post.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in  in
>   C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\site\wp-includes\functions.php on line
>   4848
>
> Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
>   C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\site\wp-includes\functions.php on line
>   4851
>
> Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
>   C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\site\wp-includes\functions.php on line
>   4854

На которые указывает следующие строки кода в **functions.php**

```
/**
 * Retrieve metadata from a file.
 *
 * Searches for metadata in the first 8kiB of a file, such as a plugin or theme.
 * Each piece of metadata must be on its own line. Fields can not span multiple
 * lines, the value will get cut at the end of the first line.
 *
 * If the file data is not within that first 8kiB, then the author should correct
 * their plugin file and move the data headers to the top.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/File_Header
 *
 * @since 2.9.0
 *
 * @param string $file            Path to the file.
 * @param array  $default_headers List of headers, in the format array('HeaderKey' => 'Header Name').
 * @param string $context         Optional. If specified adds filter hook {@see 'extra_$context_headers'}.
 *                                Default empty.
 * @return array Array of file headers in `HeaderKey => Header Value` format.
 */
function get_file_data( $file, $default_headers, $context = '' ) {
  // We don't need to write to the file, so just open for reading.
  $fp = fopen( $file, 'r' );

  // Pull only the first 8kiB of the file in.
  $file_data = fread( $fp, 8192 );

  // PHP will close file handle, but we are good citizens.
  fclose( $fp );

  // Make sure we catch CR-only line endings.
  $file_data = str_replace( "\r", "\n", $file_data );
...
}
```

Как можно их исправить? Если плагин деактивирую - ошибка исчезает. Как можно исправить ошибки в включенным плагином?

Или это ошибка только из-за локального сервера? Кеш очищал.

P.S. Перед функцией `fopen` вставил следующую запись

```
error_log('$file: ' . print_r($file, true) . PHP_EOL , 3, __DIR__ . '/log.log');
```

В итоге получаю:

> $file:
>   C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\site/wp-content/plugins/C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\site\wp-content\plugins\wp-hide-post\wp-hide-post.php
>
> $file:
>   C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\site/wp-content/plugins/wp-hide-post/index.php
>
> $file:
>   C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\site/wp-content/plugins/wp-hide-post/uninstall.php
>
> $file:
>   C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\site/wp-content/plugins/wp-hide-post/wp-hide-post.php

объявление константы
`define('WPHP_PLUGIN_DIR', __DIR__ . "/");`

```
public function define_globals()
    {

        $this->info['dir'] = WPHP_PLUGIN_DIR;
        $this->info['url'] = WPHP_PLUGIN_URL;

        $this->info['title']    = __('WP Hide Post', 'scb_plugin');
        $this->info['file']     = WPHP_PLUGIN_FILE;
        $this->info['basename'] = plugin_basename($this->info['file']);
    }
}
```

> object(wp_hide_post)#7451 (6) { array(5) { ["dir"]=> string(72)
>   "C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\site\wp-content\plugins\wp-hide-post/"
>
> ["url"]=> string(60) "localhost/site/wp-content/plugins/wp-hide-post"
>
> ["title"]=> string(12) "WP Hide Post" ["file"]=> string(88)
>   "C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\site\wp-content\plugins\wp-hide-post\wp-hide-post.php"
>
> ["basename"]=> string(29) "wp-hide-post/wp-hide-post.php" }
>
> }

Comment: Ну нет файла `wp-content\plugins\wp-hide-post\wp-hide-post.php`

Comment: @KAGG Design ну как же нету - есть. Обновил ответ, вот какие пути получаю